# What is the best way to write videos captured from webcam by OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, ffmpeg

I have started using OpenCV with python recently and upon using [this method](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video) to write a video file I was not content as 10 seconds of video were resulting in 1GB files.

What is the recommended way to do it? Use external tools like ffmpeg is something considered good practice for this type of thing?

Comment: What video codecs (DIVX, H264 etc) have you tried?

Comment: I only tried it with MJPG because I read somewhere on OpenCV page that this was the only one tested on all platforms (Linux, Win, Mac).